# Which prepositions are used for indirect objects?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I'm trying to better understand verb phrases with indirect objects. My starting point is that indirect object is usually marked with à, but à can also be "just a preposition", and the reliable way to tell a difference is to see whether the object can be replaced by an indirect object **pronoun**:

- Je parle à Jean => Je lui parle (indirect object)
- Je pense à Jean => *Je lui pense (NOT indirect object)
- Je vais à Paris => *Je lui vais (NOT indirect object)

Apparently sometimes the same verb can sometimes use à to mark an indirect object, and other times use à "as a preposition":

- J'envoie mes livres à Marie (indirect object)
- J'envoie mes livres à Paris (NOT indirect object)

Questions:

1. Is the above correct? Is there a standard way to call phrases like "penser à Jean" or "envoyer à Paris", if they're not verbs with indirect objects?
2. What prepositions can be used to introduce indirect objects? I thought it was only à, but then saw an example with "acheter pour" which apparently is also considered a verb taking an indirect object. Is there a fixed list of prepositions that can introduce indirect objects? In particular, can **de** ever introduce an indirect object?
3. Is there a list of all verbs taking indirect objects, such that e.g. "donner à" and "parler à" are in it, but "penser à" and "aller à" are not? I understand that some very frequent verbs are such, e.g. donner and parler, but is it otherwise a large category of verbs, or a small set that can be usefully enumerated?

Comment: Je pense à Jean : indirect object => Je pense à lui. lui is a pronoun, and the associated question is "à qui je pense" to whom I'm thinking. / Je vais à Paris : not a indirect object, the associated question is Where do I go , Où vais-je ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO, but if we call "Je pense à Jean" an indirect object construction, then how do we understand the difference between "Je parle à Jean" and "Je pense à Jean"? In one case it's possible to say "Je lui parle", in the other it's impossible to say "*Je lui pense". If both are indirect objects, where does the difference come from?

Comment: It's about verbs being "transitifs" or not. It depends on the meaning you give to the verb : _Je pense quelquechose_ (transitif direct) : quelquechose is **what** I think, it is the thought, the **object** (content) of the thought. _Je pense à quelqu'un_ (transitif indirect) : quelqu'un is **to whom** (or to what) I think. It's not the thought itself but **the subject** of the thought. Finally, _je pense_ (used as intransitif) describes the action, without saying neither the content nor the subject.

Comment: You can also use both : _je pense quelquechose de quelqu'un_ with the preposition _de_ introducing the indirect object (your question 2).

Comment: Som verbs are always _intransitifs_ : je marche, I walk. You can't say _I walk something_ or _I walk of | at something_. (you can say to or towards somewhere but then it's not object). And some verbs are always _transitifs_ like dire, to say. You always say **something**, you can't just say _I say_. Finally, it's the same in french and english.

Comment: Lol I just realized I didn't answer your question at all. I try to figure it out but I'm not sure : parler is always _intransitif_, penser is _transitif_, I guess it's related but can't say how... Interesting ! However, dire is _transitif_ and I'd say _je lui dis_...

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Je pense à Jean : à Jean is *complément d'objet indirect*, J'envoie à Paris : à Paris is *complément circonstanciel de lieu* (unless it's Paris Hilton)

**2.** Prepositions are more often `à` or `de` (*je dépends de quelqu'un*), but can also be `pour`, `contre` (*je me bats contre lui*), `en` (*je crois en Dieu*), `sur` (*je compte sur toi*), `envers, avec`  (*il est bon envers, avec moi*)... (I hope everything is correct here, but people will correct me if not).

**3.** I think I finally got the answer :

- There are verbs **not pronominal and not transitive** like courir. Here, no question.
- Verbs **not pronominal and transitive direct** : like *prendre*. Je prends quelquechose => *Je le/la prends*. You can put a pronoun and it's `le/la/les` because the pronoun is put for the direct object.
- Verbs that can be **pronominal but only reflexive** (self), like *penser*.

  - When **used in its pronominal** form, you can put a pronoun (of course)
    : `me/te/se/nous/vous/se`, reflexive pronouns. *Je me pense comme quelqu'un de bien* (a bit weird I admit)
  - Used in a **not pronominal form as a transitive indirect verb**, like in *Je pense à Jean, je crois en Dieu*, you can't put a pronoun.
  - Used in a **not pronominal form and transitive direct** : *Je pense quelquechose, je crois ma femme*, then you can put a pronoun : `le/la/les` (*Je le pense*, *Je la crois*...)
- Verbs that can be **reciprocal pronominal** (each other), like *(se) parler, (s')aimer, (se) rencontrer*, can take a pronoun.

  - If **the verb is transitive and the pronoun is put for the direct object**  it's `le/la/les` : *je rencontre les gens : je les rencontre, j'aime Jean : je l'aime*. (`l'` being a form of `le`).
  - If **the verb is not transitive**, the pronoun is put for the indirect object, then the pronoun is `lui/leur` : *je parle à Jean => Je lui parle, je parle à mes parents => je leur parle, etc...*
  - Finally **if the verb is transitive BUT also has an indirect object** : *J'écris une lettre à mes parents*, then it depends on what the pronoun is put for. If it's for the direct object, it's  `l'/le/la/les` : *Cette lettre, je l'écris à mes parents*, and if it's for indirect object, it's `lui/leur` : *Je leur écris une lettre*. And wait, just for fun, you can use both : *Je la leur écris*.

Who said french is not simple ? Is it not wonderful ?