# What is the nuance between "préparer qqch à qqn" and "préparer qqch pour qqn"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

In a [different](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43863/can-indirect-object-pronouns-replace-indirect-objects-that-are-introduced-with-c) question, an answerer said this:

> In all of those uses, the dative pronouns correspond to noun phrases
> marked by the preposition à. In one of those uses, it overlaps with
> the (semantically motivated) use of the preposition pour to mark
> beneficiaries of an action:
>
> > Je prépare un bon petit plat **à** mes enfants > je leur prépare un bon
> > petit plat
> >
> > Je prépare un bon petit plat **pour** mes enfants > je prépare un bon
> > petit plat pour eux
>
> But as you can see from the correspondence above, this semantic
> overlap doesn't mean that there is a syntactic link between "je leur
> prépare un plat" and "je prépare un plat pour mes enfants". Presenting
> it as the pronoun leur replacing the noun phrase "pour mes enfants" is
> simply wrong. **They're two different sentences that mean almost the
> same thing.**

Given that English has only one preposition to mark the idea of Beneficiary for this sentence ("I am preparing a small dish **for** my kids"), I'm wondering: What is the (nuanced) difference between

- "Je prépare un bon petit plat à mes enfants" vs
- "Je prépare un bon petit plat pour mes enfants"

?

That is, is there a nuanced difference .. in meaning? .. in register? .. in typical contexts one is used more than the other? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context *can* require a particular choice that will carry a nuance, but ever so small that I believe it hardly possible to make an argument about its value. Usually there is no nuance.

- Je prépare un bon petit plat *pour* mes enfants, pas *pour* elle car malgré tout le mal que je me donne elle dénigre vicieusement ma cuisine.

"À" would not be quite as expressive, and possibly not quite idiomatic; it is not a preposition that communicates its semantic function as vividly as others, this being due, at least in part, to the great number of functions that have been piled up upon it ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)). Therefore the idea of someone being a beneficiary is made more salient by the use of "pour". I would not argue against the use of "à" in that sentence but I definitely prefer "pour".

Anyway, let's notice that "à" is not at all proper in front of pronouns when use in this sense (pour).

- Je les prépare pour elle. <s>Je les prépare à elle.</s>

This shows again that this preposition, in some of its uses, is lacking somewhat in specificity, in clarity as to what it communicates.

Comment: Is "Je prépare un bon plat à ma copine" acceptable, but "Je prépare un bon plat à elle" not? This surprises me! I don't understand why simply using the pronoun *elle* instead of *ma copine* would make the sentence unacceptable!

Comment: @silph That's just something I know (internalized), and I am quite at a loss telling you why it is so; I am just as puzzled as you are. I'd have to do some research.