# Direct object pronoun with Manquer à

Tags: constructions

New French learner going through some sentences. Came across:

"*Il est seulement parti depuis trois jours, mais il me manque terriblement.*"

Which translates to:

"*He has only been gone for three days, but I miss him terribly.*"

After some googling I've become aware of the strange structure of *manquer à* but my question is why does the part ***mais il me manque terriblement*** use ***il*** as the direct object pronoun for ***him*** instead of ***le***.

Would it be wrong to say: *"Il est seulement parti depuis trois jours, mais le me manque terriblement"*?

If you were to say *I punch him* it would it not be *je le frappe*? Why is this different for *I miss him*? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About "unusual" word order?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/978/about-unusual-word-order)

Comment: The English structure "I miss you" is just as strange to French ears (and sometimes triggers jokes).

Comment: Cela me manque. I miss it [some thing]. Il me manque/I miss him. It's like Cela me plait. I like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*(Note: I am at a late-beginner / low-intermediate learner of French, so I welcome others to point out inaccurate information that I might write in this answer.)*</sub>

---

> Would it be wrong to say: "Il est seulement parti depuis trois jours,
> mais le me manque terriblement"?

It would be wrong to say that, for the same reason that it would be wrong to write the sentence alone: "**Le** me manque terriblement". The correct sentence is instead "**Il** me manque terriblement".

The word *il* is a [subject pronoun](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/subject-pronouns/). Common subject pronouns you've probably learned about are: je, tu, il, elle, nous, vous, ils, elles. (You might have also learned about *on*).

Most sentences (that is, aside from greetings like "Bonjour") need a subject! "Le me manque terriblement" does not have a subject. ("Le me manque terriblement" literally translates into "Him is-missing to me terribly", which doesn't work in English, either; but "He is-missing to me terribly" does work, because it has a subject (the subject is "he"))

---

> If you were to say I punch him it would it not be je le frappe? Why is
> this different for I miss him?

There are at least two important things that you need to understand, in order to translate "I miss him":

- Understanding direct vs indirect objects; and then using object pronouns to replace a direct object or an indirect object.
- The surprising (for English speakers) way that *manquer à* works. I assume you already understand this from your readings, but hopefully the examples later on in this answer will further clarify your confusion.

**Direct vs Indirect Objects**

Consider the following two sentences:

1. I phone Marc. *Je telephone **à Marc**.*
2. I punch Marc. *Je frappe **Marc**.*

In French, indirect objects always begin<sup>1</sup> with a preposition (almost always *à* or *de*<sup>4</sup>, but sometimes *pour* <sup>2</sup>), and direct objects never have a preposition.

In "Je téléphone **à Marc**", "à Marc" is an indirect object.
In "Je frappe **Marc**", "Marc" is a direct object.

You can use an **indirect object pronoun** to replace an indirect object<sup>3</sup> :

> I phone Marc. *Je téléphone **à Marc**.*
> --> I phone him. *Je **lui** téléphone.*

You can use a **direct object pronoun** to replace a direct object:

> I punch Marc. *Je frappe **Marc***.
> --> I punch him. *Je **le** frappe*.

---

Here is another example. My own name is David; suppose I say these sentences:

Alex phones David. *Alex téléphone **à David***.
--> Alex phones me. *Alex **me** téléphone*.

Alex punches David. *Alex frappe **David**.*
--> Alex punches me. *Alex **me** frappe.*

Here,

- you see that in "Alex *me* téléphone", *me* is an **in**direct object pronoun, because it replaced an indirect object ("à David").
- you see that in "Alex *me* frappe", *me* is a **direct** object pronoun, because it replaced a direct object ("David").

---

Your question title says: "Direct object pronoun with Manquer à". Now you know that when using "manquer *à quelqu'un*" ("to be-missing to someone"), you won't ever use a direct object pronoun; you will have to use an indirect object pronoun, because when you see *à quelqu'un*, you know that it is an indirect object.

Now suppose I speak these sentences (remembering that my name is David) :

Il manque à David. *("He is-missing to David", or in more natural English, "David misses him")*.
--> Il me manque. *("He is-missing to me", or in more natural English, "I miss him")*

Hopefully you can now see why "Il me manque terriblement" is correct, and why "Le me manque terriblement" is incorrect.

---

Possibly helpful reading (though I didn't read these carefully, so I'm not sure helpful they actually will be) :

- https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/direct-vs-indirect-objects/
- https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/personal-pronouns-indirect-object
- https://duonotes.fandom.com/wiki/French#Verbs:_Present_2
- https://languageguide.org/french/grammar/V&O

---

<sup>Footnote 1: Some French grammar websites/textbooks will say (as I do here) that "à Marc" is an indirect object; and some will say that only "Marc" is an indirect object, but that it is preceded by "à". In practice, both views work; there isn't any real consequence about how to analyse grammar (e.g. you won't be deciding on which indirect pronoun to use any differently, etc, regardless of which view you take)</sup>

<sup>Footnote 2: Indirect objects *might* be introduced by prepositions other than à, de, and pour -- I don't have 100% understanding of this. But it [seems](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43863/can-indirect-object-pronouns-replace-indirect-objects-that-are-introduced-with-c) that, when only considering indirect objects that can be replaced using object pronouns, à, de, and occasionally pour will always introduce the indirect object.</sup>

<sup>Footnote 3: Choosing the correct indirect object pronoun to replace an indirect object isn't straightforward; I'm choosing not to try to explain how to choose the correct indirect object pronoun in this answer.</sup>

<sup>Footnote 4: Some French grammar websites and textbooks consider objects introduced by "de" to not be indirect objects; and some French grammar websites and textbooks do. In either case, "de + noun" is replaced with the pronoun *en*. The French grammar websites that consider "de + noun" to *not* be indirect objects will talk about replacing them with the "adverbial pronoun *en*" instead of replacing them with an "indirect object pronoun *en*"</sup>

---

<sup>The textbook "Advanced French Grammar" by Monique L'Huillier definitely calls "à Marc" (ie, including the preposition) an indirect object:</sup>

[image]

<sup>and both this textbook, and the textbook "The structure of Modern Standard French" by Mosegaard Hansen, seem to consider objects introduced by *de* to be indirect objects; whereas all the websites I linked to only consider objects introduced by *à* and *pour* to be indirect objects.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot to patch up my fundamentals! :)

Comment: @Happytwig you're welcome!